# MySQLi export to csv

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a script that works but I cannot seem to adjust or find the output file.
I would like the file to go to a specific directory when generated - at the moment it saves I think as test1.csv but I cannot actually find where this file is so not 100% sure it is being generated.

So ideally it would go to a directory like /var/www/html/administration/csvs in my case

```
include  ('/var/www/html/administration/connections/connection.php');
$query = "CALL report_c05($system_id,$entity_id, $client_idx, '$start_date',    '$end_date')";
$result = $con->query($query);
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$headers = $result->fetch_fields();
foreach($headers as $header) {
    $head[] = $header->name;
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test1.csv"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
fputcsv($fp, array_values($head)); 
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
die;
}
```

Any idea please.

A secondary issue is - this runs as a cron job - and the cron log now contains all the output for this query - not very helpful - can I do anything about this?

thanks

Thanks Luigi :
Full working code for the next person with my problems:

```
include  ('/var/www/html/administration/connections/connection.php');
$query = "CALL report_c05($system_id,$entity_id, $client_idx, '$start_date',     '$end_date')";
$result = $con->query($query);
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$headers = $result->fetch_fields();
foreach($headers as $header) {
$head[] = $header->name;
}
$fp = fopen('/var/www/html/administration/test1.csv', 'x');
if ($fp && $result) {
fputcsv($fp, array_values($head)); 
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
die;
}
```

Comment: Once check whether the file is generating in the same folder where this program is located... and also once check the MySQL folder.. Once when i did this.. My file got copied into MySQL folder in WAMP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing to `php://output`. See the [PHP manual on I/O streams](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php). Since you are running the script inside a cronjob, `php://output` will write to the standard output, which the cron daemon will nicely present you in its logs, depending on its configuration.

Also, there is no point in sending HTTP headers, since you are not doing HTTP.

You should simply `fopen()` the output file you want and `fputcsv()` your data in it.

Comment: I added to my question based on your answer